# Opencart Region/State does not populate when Country is selected

Tags: validation, opencart, zones

I am using Opencart Version 2.0.3.1. When I select Singapore as country while registration or checkout, the corresponding Region/State does not load up. This is not the case for other countries. So when I went to the backend, I just found out that there were no zones added for Singapore. Does anyone have a list of valid Opencart zones for Singapore so that i do not have to edit the validation code to skip Region/State.

Comment: Have you checked console for any ajax request? Which passes when you change the country.

Comment: @ved-pandya Yes, I have. The ajax request works fine. The problem is that there is no zones added for Singapore. There are other countries too where zones are not present along with the Opencart installation. I need to know if Opencart provides a list missing zones that I can add from the backend.

Answer (score 0):

For Singapore country, you have to add zones.

**Add zone**

> System -> Localisation -> Zones

Comment: I am aware of that option, I want to know if there is a valid and authentic list of zones for Singapore and other countries which does not have default zones added with Opencart installation

Comment: The issue was solved by the theme provider. It had to do with the ajax requests.